# how can I execute these dynamically generated statements dynamically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following SQL will generate DROP statements for all tables in a database:

```
 -- generate all drop table statements
SELECT 'DROP TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.NAME + '];'
FROM sys.tables t
```

The Results output from the statement above can be copied to a new query window in SSMS and executed to drop all the tables in the database. I'm trying to skip the manual step above. What SQL can I write to dynamically execute the statements which are generated from the statement above?

Comment: Put it into a variable and execute it... e.g. `declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''; select @sql += 'DROP TABLE... exec sp_executesql @sql;`

Comment: Tip: [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) will handle escaping brackets correctly rather than simply adding them to object names.

Comment: This is one of the situations where a `CURSOR` will excel.

Answer (score 0):

The example below assigns the concatenated results to a variable for execution. In SQL Server 2017, use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) instead of XML PATH.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = 
    (SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';
'
FROM sys.tables t
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note that a drop will fail if the table is referenced by a foreign key constraint. You can avoid that by first dropping all foreign key constraints using a similar technique.